# Show Moving Average by Week in KPI Card in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm developing a DAX formula to compute a 4-week rolling average based on selected weeks. If I choose Week 1 from the slicer, the average will be the sum of Week 1 divided by 1. If Week 2 is selected, it will be divided by 2. However, if Week 4 or later is chosen, the average will be divided by 4.

DAX:

```
_4WeekRollingAverage# = 
VAR CurrentWeek = MAX(Responsiveness[Week])

VAR WeeksToConsider =
    IF(
        CurrentWeek >= 4,
        4,
        CurrentWeek
    )

VAR _PreviousWeek =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Responsiveness[Volume]),
        Responsiveness[Week] >= CurrentWeek - WeeksToConsider + 1 && Responsiveness[Week] <= CurrentWeek
    )

RETURN
    DIVIDE(_PreviousWeek, WeeksToConsider)
```

However, this produces incorrect results when I select only one week in a slicer, unless week 1 is selected. Conversely, it yields accurate results when I select multiple weeks in the slicer.

For Ex.

```
WEEK     Volume
1        512
2        725 
3        798
4        721
```

When selected 2 in a slicer, it gives 618 on KPI card but when I select 1 & 2 it gives 619. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I tried several methods but nothing is working.

Comment: Add `ALL(Responsiveness)` to your `CALCULATE` so it can see all the rows and not just those selected in the slicer.

Comment: It does not help, I have a situation where all these weeks have multiple values. Even if I use ALL(Responsiveness[Week]), it does not help.

Comment: Do you have any rows with blank/null weeks in your table?

Comment: No, nothing is blank in the table for weeks.

Comment: What value do you get when 1, 2, 3 selected vs 2, 3 selected?

Comment: The outcome remains consistent at 678 in both scenarios, yet my aim is to attain this outcome solely when selecting 3. However, it currently yields 671.

Comment: Bizarre, could you share a link to a sample PBIX (via One Drive, Google Drive, Drop Box, etc...)?